# How to load a webpage (Https using a self signed certificate) on the UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How to load a webpage (Https using a self signed certificate) on the UIWebView (iOS)? I tried using NSURLConnection and I am able to load the NSMutableData to the UIwebView. But in this case I am not able to see the images in that page.

Answer (score 1):

```
[yourWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourUrlGoesHere"]]];
```

And about the certificates part if your URL openable in Safari it will open in a webview.

---

Update for the comment

Try the below

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourUrlGoesHere"]];
NSURLConnection *urlConnection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
[yourWebView loadRequest:req];
```

and implement the following delegate methods in your class,

```
#pragma mark - NSURLConnection Delegate Methods
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Comment: When i try to open the URL in Safari,  i will get an error message saying that it is not safe going in. If i click on Continue will take me to the web page. I am making an HTTPS call which is using a self signed certificate.

Comment: I had tried this method. I am getting the NSMutable Data from the response. But when i try to load it to the webview i am not able to see the images in the Webpage. I am posting the sample code. Could you please tell me if i am missing something.**- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection { 
[self.k_webView loadData:data MIMEType:mimeType textEncodingName: @"UTF-8" baseURL:nil]; }**

Answer (score 0):

Self signed certificates most of the time can not be validated by client, thats why the client can not load the data, because it can not validate from server.

Certificates uses domains to validate itself so it is a bit hard to have on development environment.

There is a tool which creates for local environment certificate, i am not sure how it is internally working my best thought is it adds another CA file on your environment.

You may want to check [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert) it is very easy to use nice workaround.